# Rstudio project using different version of R

Tags: r, rstudio, portable-applications

Rstudio can change the version of R it uses (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R). Is there a way to do this for a specific project?

*Context*: I'm building an R-based application by bundling R-portable with my code and some other scripts to make it all work. I'd like to work on my project from within RStudio, using the portable version of R within the app, without changing my R version for every other RStudio project I work on.

Comment: You can have several R installations on the same system and select the one you want to use in the RStudio preferences: Tools --> Global Options --> General --> R version (change).

Comment: Great feature when an R package is outdated, didn't know that!

Comment: @Roland Is there a way to do this in a project-specific way, though? I don't want to have to remember to manually change my R installation every time I switch between projects - I know I'm going to forget to do it eventually and cause all sorts of problems for myself.

Comment: I wonder whether it is possible, because selecting R version is a global option and such an option is not given at project level.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but if you really want to remind you that you have matching R version in a RStudio project, you could force the stop of the script if the version number does not match:

```
if (!(version$major == "3") | !(version$minor == "4.3")) { 
  stop(paste0("Version ",version$major,".",version$minor," is in use. R version 3.4.3 is required. Exiting.")) 
}

Error: Version 3.4.2 is in use. R version 3.4.3 is required. Exiting.
```

That will remind you to change the R version number from RStudio's global options.