# Link Project and R Version

Tags: r, rstudio, olap

I have two different versions of R installed, one which is up to date and which I use for all my regular R coding (needs to be up to date so that I can use various updated and new packages) and one which I use to access OLAP cubes (needs to be the R Client from Microsoft, because this is the only one which supports the `olapR` package, and which currently uses R version 3.4.3).

Since, in theory, I only have to access the OLAP cube once a month, I "outsourced" this task to a different RStudio project, in which I download and save the required data for all other projects. Hence, all other projects never require the `olapR` package to be installed and can and will be run in the up to date R version.

Now, ideally I would like to link my R version to my projects, so that I do not have to change my global R version and restart RStudio every time I access the OLAP cube or work on this data retrieval project (and then switch it back). However, I could not find any options in RStudio to achieve this result.

There are a few threads out there describing the same problem, but with no satisfactory answer in my opinion:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200657296-Link-Project-and-R-Version

[Rstudio project using different version of R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771608/rstudio-project-using-different-version-of-r)

I also tried looking for a different package than `olapR` but with similar functionality, but could not find anything except X4R, which seems outdated and does not work for me (https://github.com/overcoil/X4R). Sadly, I am also unable to directly access the databases which the OLAP cube uses for its results, so I cannot go "around" it.

I am happy for any help or suggestions you can offer, whether it is a general workaround to link a project to a specific R version or the (less helpful for the community) solution of accessing the OLAP cube in a different way.

Thanks in advance!

---

---

Using the answer from MrGumble I created a .bat file that will execute my .R file using the desired R installation. Even though it is not the answer I thought I would get, I think it is an even better solution to the problem.

For all facing a similar issue, here is the .bat file (never created one before, so also had to google how to do it and I guess some might be in the same position):

```
@echo off
title Getting data for further processing in R
echo Retrieving OLAP data
echo. 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Client\R_SERVER\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\me\Documents\Projects\!Data\script.R"
echo. 
echo Saved data
echo. 
pause
```

Thanks again to MrGumble for his help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip RStudio.

RStudio is really just an editor (albeit powerful and useful) editor, which starts an R console for you (and the surrounding PATH variables, library locations, etc.).

If your monthly task only requires you to run the R-script (or a bit of interactive work), you can simply execute your preferred version of R from the command line and have it run your R script. E.g.

```
C:\Users\me>"C:\Program Files (x64)\Microsoft R\bin\Rscript" myscript.R
```

You might have to define some PATH variables so that the older R doesn't look for packages in the newer R's libraries, but that depends entirely on your current setup.

Comment: Amazing! That is definitely the best way to do it, thanks for helping me out :)